# Can´t read and format date column from html page properly

Tags: python, html, dataframe

I´ve got a problem with parsing the date column in the right format. I am reading data from a HTML  page with `pd.read_html`. The data I am reading looks like this:

[image: picture: data source]

Here the [URL](https://www.onvista.de/onvista/times+sales/popup/historische-kurse/?notationId=253929&dateStart=30.04.2018&interval=M3&assetName=Apple&exchange=Nasdaq) to the data.

I am reading as following:

```
list = pd.read_html("https://www.onvista.de/onvista/times+sales/popup/historische-kurse/?notationId=253929&dateStart=30.04.2018&interval=M3&assetName=Apple&exchange=Nasdaq", header=0, parse_dates=[0],  decimal=',', thousands='.')
```

When I print somehow some of the dates switched month with day. For instance row 0 looks fine, but for the rows 1 - 9 switched months and days. Row 10 and 11 look fine again. It happens in all month for first few days.

[image: picture: output with parsing date]

I tried to load the data without parsing the date column to datetime, so I could format the column as I wished, but if I print the dataframe the column has lost the separate `.` .

[image: picture: output without parsing date]

Does anyone have an idea how I can read the data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the parse_dates isn't functioning, but you can use `datetime` and panda's DataFrame `apply` method to convert dates.  One note - this appears slightly convoluted because the days in the dates are missing zero padding:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
lista = pd.read_html("https://www.onvista.de/onvista/times+sales/popup/historische-kurse/?notationId=253929&dateStart=30.04.2018&interval=M3&assetName=Apple&exchange=Nasdaq", header=0,  decimal=',', thousands='.')
df = lista[0]
df['Datum'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['Datum'].astype(str)[:-2], '%d%m%Y')
                       if len(x['Datum'].astype(str)[:-2]) == 8 else 
                       datetime.strptime('0' + x['Datum'].astype(str)[:-2], '%d%m%Y'), axis=1)
```

And this returns:

```
Datum   Eröffnung   Hoch    Tief    Schluss Volumen
0   2018-04-30  162.19  167.26  161.840 165.26  42427424
1   2018-05-01  166.35  169.20  165.270 169.10  53569376
2   2018-05-02  175.25  177.75  173.800 176.57  66539371
3   2018-05-03  175.68  177.50  174.441 176.89  34068180
4   2018-05-04  178.17  184.25  178.170 183.83  56201317
```